# Java - Derby - JDBC - NullPointerException PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception, derby

I've a problem with my program.

I use a Derby database and connect with JDBC on it. But everytime I get a nullpointerexception when calling a functions that have "do something" with the database.

So this is the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: ': java.lang.NullPointerException'.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.javaException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at notetool.database.Database_Manager.getCatDirs(Database_Manager.java:161)
at Notetool.<init>(Notetool.java:30)
at Notetool.main(Notetool.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: ': java.lang.NullPointerException'.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.derby.iapi.types.TypeId.getTypeId(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.types.DataTypeDescriptor.getType(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.SYSCOLUMNSRowFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndexMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndex(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.finishTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptorIndex1Scan(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getUncachedTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.NameTDCacheable.setIdentity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
... 10 more
```

Line number 161 is following:

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM dir");
```

And the complete function:

```
public ArrayList<String> getCatDirs() {
    con = initConnection();
    ArrayList<String> dirs = new ArrayList<String>();
    ResultSet resultSet;

    try {

        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM dir");
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        int columnCnt = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCnt;i++){
              dirs.add(resultSet.getString(i) +  " ");
            }
          }

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(dirid) FROM dir");
        columnCnt = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while( resultSet.next()) {
            setCatIds(resultSet.getInt(columnCnt));
        }

        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return dirs;
}
```

And here is also the initConnection() function

```
public Connection initConnection() {
    try {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:db/notedb;create=true;user=admin;password=1234;schema=admin");

    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return con;
}
```

I really don't know whats the problem. And about and hour ago it worked fine.

Maybe this helps, it's the output from the derby.log

```
------------  BEGIN SHUTDOWN ERROR STACK -------------

ERROR XSDB0: Unexpected exception on in-memory page Page(5,Container(0, 144))
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.StoredPage.initSlotTable(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.StoredPage.initFromData(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.CachedPage.setIdentity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.getUserPage(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.getPage(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseContainerHandle.getPage(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.conglomerate.OpenConglomerate.latchPage(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.conglomerate.GenericConglomerateController.fetch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndexMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndex(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.finishTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptorIndex1Scan(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getUncachedTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.NameTDCacheable.setIdentity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at notetool.database.Database_Manager.getCatDirs(Database_Manager.java:161)
at Notetool.<init>(Notetool.java:30)
at Notetool.main(Notetool.java:23)


------------  END SHUTDOWN ERROR STACK -------------

Fri Jan 03 23:19:42 CET 2014 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 1389), (SESSIONID = 1),        (DATABASE = db/notedb), (DRDAID = null), Cleanup action starting
Fri Jan 03 23:19:42 CET 2014 Thread[main,5,main] (XID = 1389), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = db/notedb), (DRDAID = null), Failed Statement is: SELECT name FROM dir
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.derby.iapi.types.TypeId.getTypeId(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.types.DataTypeDescriptor.getType(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.SYSCOLUMNSRowFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndexMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getDescriptorViaIndex(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getColumnDescriptorsScan(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.finishTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptorIndex1Scan(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getUncachedTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.NameTDCacheable.setIdentity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at notetool.database.Database_Manager.getCatDirs(Database_Manager.java:161)
at Notetool.<init>(Notetool.java:30)
at Notetool.main(Notetool.java:23)
Cleanup action completed
```

So as already said, about two hours ago it worked fine. I added a table with SquirrelSQL to the database, what worked, but suddenly it crashed and I have no idea how to get it working again.

Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your database has become corrupt, unfortunately.

Do you have database backups that you can restore from?

This is not supposed to happen and could indicate a bug in Derby.

Before you try to reproduce the problem, you should save your database folder and your derby.log and any other information you can collect, and contact the developers on the derby-dev mailing list; perhaps they can help you figure out how the database became corrupt.

Include any information you can about which version of Derby you're using, which version of Java, which operating system you're running on, etc.

Can you reproduce this problem with a fresh empty database?

When you added the table using Squirrel, was your program also running at the same time?

Were there any other odd events which occurred just prior to the database becoming corrupted? (Your program crashed, your machine crashed, your disk was full, your program ran out of memory, etc.?)

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I backuped my corrupt database and created a new one and now it's working. Fortunately my database wasn't very big and complex so it was no problem.

Before it went corrupt I haven't recognized any special problems. But I'm going to send the corrupt database plus the logs to the derby-devs.

So thank you!